# Script to enter data from mysql database into text file

Tags: scripts, mysql

I have written a script to extract the contents of a table into a textfile. this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uroot -ppasswd database select * from table>textfile.txt
```

i have changed permissions on the file and when i run it using `./myscript` it creates textfile.txt but loads into it the mysql manual.How can i achieve my desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows you the manual because it's the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
mysql -uroot -ppasswd database -e "select * from table" >textfile.txt
```

From the manual:

```
-e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history file.)
```